# Calculate matrix values as average of all pairwise comparisons in a list in R

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I have a list:
`list <- c(10,20,30)`

I would like to create a matrix of mean values of all pairwise comparisons of the elements in the list like:
[image]

I have tried:
`meanmatrix <- (list + list) / 2`

but that gives:
10 40 90

I have tried:
`meanmatrix <- apply(list, 1, mean)`

but that gives:

> "Error in apply(lister, 1, sum) : dim(X) must have a positive length"

I have done this in vb.net with a For Loop but I know there must be a better way in R.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You want the outer product.

```
outer(list, list, "+") / 2

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   10   15   20
# [2,]   15   20   25
# [3,]   20   25   30
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Works perfect.